# Parsing text from out HTML website in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

Im new in PHP and wanna make a little script.
I need to parse info from ex. http://sample.com/value.php
This is html:

```
   <ul>
  <li>Value: 100<ul>
   <li>Note: abcd </li>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Note: adad<ul>
   <li>Note: qweqw </li>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
<ul>
  <li>Value: 200<ul>
   <li>Note: abcd </li>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
```

But in my script I need to parse only info with value (Value: 100, Value: 200) website got a lot of code about 200-300 lines. ul and li don't have any class so I can't use getElementsByTagName(). Anybody know how solve that problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Use PHP library to parse HTML and don't even think about RegEx

Comment: Since you mention `getElementsByTagName()` I presume that you need to parse HTML with javascript? Or can it be done with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing html using DOMXpath:

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($YOUR_HTML);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$lis = $xpath->query("//li/text()");
if (!is_null($lis)) {
    foreach ($lis as $li) {
        if (preg_match('~^Value: (.+?)$~', $li->nodeValue, $m)) {
            print_r($m);
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/604650)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

use strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

```
$myCleanText = strip_tags ($YOUR_HTML));
```